# Viewing Image with Laravel backend with Apache

Tags: php, laravel, image, rest

I have images stored in my storage/app/images folder.

However, I cannot access or view any of these images on localhost without a 404 header.

I'm using Apache with the following htaccess to my Laravel REST API

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /backendLaravel/public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I followed the `php artisan storage:link` that Laravel Docs provide, however nothing changes.

I want to be able to access these files publicly using http. So, http://endpoint/SDUpload/hello.jpeg

How do I achieve this

Answer (score 0):

`storage:link` creates a symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`. Try either moving your `storage/app/images` folder to `storage/app/public/images` or create a symbolic link from `public/storage/images` to `storage/app/images` with: `ln -s storage/app/images public/storage/images`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but I'm assuming it would work. In Laravel there is a public_path() helper as well as a storage_path() helper. If you are trying to display these images online in your html, you can try to use the storage helper. Each of these helpers are used to access the given directory, either storage or public.

Example:

```
<img src="{{ storage_path('app/images/image.jpg')">
```

Hope I could help.

Comment: Im trying to access the images via http.

Comment: Creating a symbolic link or storing your photos in the public folder would be the best option then. :)

Comment: Doesnt work. I'm doing $path = $request->file('file')->store('SDUpload','public'); This is storing in the public/SDuploads, but I cannot retrieve it with a url.

Comment: Can you give an example of the url you're using to try and retrieve images? Also does your web server have permissions to access the images?

Comment: http://localhost/SDUpload/zktbrdiR6FyOGm7OiFzpeAccsyOKbvb7vwuSVw8d.jpeg. Yes it does.

Comment: Have you tried just placing an image in the folder by hand, instead of doing it with code?

Comment: Yes, I just tried that earlier but still no success.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192015/discussion-between-calimses-and-imjt).